# Derive the low level matrices multiplications for an autoencoder in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to derive the low level matrices multiplications and understand the architecture of the matrices for the first hidden layer of my autoencoder, but I cannot verify the result. 
My autoencoder is a 16 bits binary input encoded down to 7 and then decoded back to 16. 
I am only trying to understand the first hidden layer, "**dense_8**" in this case  and derive the multiplications according to the results further down. 

The autoencoder has been defined as follows:

```
M = 16 
N = 10000
Input(shape=(M,))
```

> <tf.Tensor 'input_6:0' shape=(None, 16) dtype=float32>

```
input_signal = Input(shape=(M,))
encoded = Dense(M, activation='relu')(input_signal)
print(encoded)
```

> Tensor("dense_8/Relu:0", shape=(None, 16), dtype=float32)

```
encoded1 = Dense(n_channel, activation='linear')(encoded)
encoded2 = BatchNormalization()(encoded1)
print (encoded1)
print (encoded2)
```

> Tensor("dense_9/BiasAdd:0", shape=(None, 7), dtype=float32)
> Tensor("batch_normalization_2/batchnorm/add_1:0", shape=(None, 7),
> dtype=float32)

And so on...

```
autoencoder.summary()
encoder.summary()
```

[image: Autoencoder model]

When I check the multiplications I cannot derive the numbers. For example below for the first 16 bits input I cannot get the output

```
layer_name = 'dense_8'

intermediate_layer_model = keras.Model(inputs=autoencoder.input, outputs=autoencoder.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_layer_model_o = keras.Model(inputs=autoencoder.input, outputs=autoencoder.get_layer(layer_name).input)


intermediate_output1 = intermediate_layer_model(data)
intermediate_input1 = intermediate_layer_model_o(data)

print ('--------THIS IS THE INPUT-------------')
print(intermediate_input1)
print ('--------THIS IS THE OUTPUT-------------')
print(intermediate_output1)

print ('--------THESE ARE THE WEIGHTS-------------')

w = np.array(encoder.weights)
print(w.shape)
print ('--------THIS IS FIRST ROW FIRST COL-------------')
print(w[0][0])
print ('--------THIS IS SEC ROW FIRST COL-------------')
print(w[1][0])
print ('--------THIS IS FIRST ROW SEC COL-------------')
print(w[0][1])
print ('--------THIS IS SEC ROW SEC COL-------------')
print(w[1][1])
print ('--------THIS IS FIRST ROW THIRD COL-------------')
print(w[0][2])


#print(w[1])
print ('--------INPUT/OUTPUT-------------')
inp = np.array(intermediate_input1)
out = np.array(intermediate_output1)
print ('---------------------')

print ('--------THIS IS THE FIRST INPUT-------------')
print(inp[0,])
print ('--------THIS IS THE FIRST OUTPUT-------------')
print(out[0,])
```

[image: Displaying the results after multiplication]

Comment: Did you make sure to include the bias term and/or activation function? Keras/TensorFlow layers almost always use these by default...

Comment: Multiplying the first input which is [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.] <br> with the weights tf.Tensor(
[ 0.05526752  0.23366453  0.08306636  0.22846253 -0.15829131  0.25428733
  0.22872673  0.21769078 -0.17981082 -0.10062635 -0.18738665 -0.10299328
 -0.37753245 -0.34754917 -0.12724707 -0.3151342 ], shape=(16,), dtype=float32) and adding the bias tf.Tensor(-0.081584, shape=(), dtype=float32) does not verify the first output <br>[0.         0.         0.         0.25333956 0.22169045 0.
 0.         0.    0.55797845 0.2548742  0.    0.
 0.42483756 0.43127206 0.   0.08672804]

Comment: What about an activation? I don't recall if Keras models/layers include one by default...